# Intriguing average value of a function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, average

**Question:**

> Let $f=e^{-kt}\sin^2(\omega t)$. Find $\langle f\rangle$ for one cycle from $t=0$ to $2\pi/\omega$.

**My attempt:**

I wished to do by first principle,

$$\langle f\rangle=\frac{\int_0^{2\pi/\omega}f d t}{\int_0^{2\pi/\omega}d t}$$

However, this involves use of integration by parts method and thus is highly convoluted. The answer in fact, is simply:

$$\langle f\rangle=\frac{e^{-kt}}{2}$$

which suggests to me that there is an alternate and more intuitive method to arrive at the result. I wished to know this method.

<sup>PS: The answer expression I've stated above has been given to me by my professor *as is*. I tried to contact him regarding the exact value of the $t$ in that expression, but he was unavailable for any further comment. The more experienced mathematicians among you may immediately spot a typo in the result if there's any, and hence please correct the same. Thank you!</sup>

Comment: The answer from your professor is not the answer to the mean of the function over the said integral.... given that you still have your variable in the answer!

Comment: @Martigan Indeed, I've the same doubt as you have. Unfortunately, I don't have any reply from the professor on this issue :(

Comment: With Maple I get $$
{\frac {{\omega}^{3}}{ \left( {k}^{2}+4\,{\omega}^{2} \right) k\pi }
 \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{-2\,{{\pi \,k}/{\omega}}}} \right) }
$$